# Advantage of declaring a variable multiple times inside different loops

Tags: c++, scope, declaration

I am aware that in c++ it is better for the variables to have as small scope as possible. 
I have a few variables that are used inside different loops but their usage is not connected between the different loops.
Should i declare these variables multiple times inside the loops (make them local variables within the loops) or declare them in the beginning of the function only one time ?
What are the advantages/disadvantages of these two methods (if there are any) ?

Comment: "I am aware that in c++ it is better for the variables to have as small scope as possible" ... "Should I declare variables in smallest scope possible" (paraphrased) ... erm yes

Comment: The smaller the scope, the better it is.

Answer (score 1):

For primitive data types there isn't really a benifit other than readability.
For other things such as classes or pointers that need expensive memory initialization it could matter.

For example:

```
int* a = new int[arrSize]; ///Calling outside loop
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    //use 'a' to do something
    for(int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++) {
        a[j] = j;
    }
    foo(a, arrSize);
    //use 'a' for some other completely unrelated task
    for((int j = 0; j < arrSize / 2; j++) {
        a[j] = j * 2;
    }
    bar(a, arrSize / 2);
}
delete[] a; ///Calling outside loop
```

Makes more sense then to call `new int[arrSize]` and `delete[] a` 1000 times like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int* a = new int[arrSize]; ///Calling inside loop
    //use 'a' to do something
    for(int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++) {
        a[j] = j + i;
    }
    foo(a, arrSize);
    //use 'a' for some other completely unrelated task
    for((int j = 0; j < arrSize / 2; j++) {
        a[j] = j * 2 + i;
    }
    bar(a, arrSize / 2);
    delete[] a; ///Calling inside loop
}
```

Comment: Good nuance. For built in types it doesn't make sense and is probably better to declare with smallest scope but for constructor heavy objects one can choose to reuse them out of performance reasons. Btw using std::vector is more maintenace freindly than new / delete array although it performs an extra initialization.